# React hook form : OnSubmit give me the reseted values (register has no effect)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup, react-hook-form

I have a problem giving me a headache with React Hook Form and Material UI.

I have a form used for creating AND updating a User and a validation with React Hook Form. There is my code :

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState({})

const schema = yup.object().shape({
    email: yup.string().email().required("Email required"),
})

const { register, handleSubmit, reset, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
    reValidateMode: 'all',
    resolver: yupResolver(schema), 
    defaultValues: user
})

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`localhost/api/user/${ route.params.userId }`).then(async r => {
        let userDatas = await r.json()
        setUser(userDatas)
    })
}, [route.params.userId])

useEffect(() => {
    if( route.params.userId && Object.keys(user).length ) {
        reset(user)
    }
}, [user])

const onSubmit = async (datas) => {
    console.log(datas)
}

const handleVerifyDuplicate = async => {
    //This function check that the email is not yet used in the database
}

return (
    <form autoComplete="off" noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <TextField
            name="email"
            label="Email"
            margin="dense"
            variant="outlined"
            required
            { ...register("email") }
            onChange={(event) => {
                register('email').onChange(event)
                handleVerifyDuplicate(event)
            }}
            defaultValue={user && user.email}
          />
          <Button
              id="btn-save"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              size="small"
              startIcon={<SaveIcon />}
              type="submit"
            >Save</Button>
    </form>
)
```

So, **on the creation it works like a charm**, but on the edition ...

If **I change** the email input and then **submit the form**, the console.log inside the onSubmit function **give me the initial value** of the user email, not the new one I just entered...

If **I remove the reset method**, the previous problem is solved... But if I **submit the form without changing** anything (onChange not triggered), it told me **it is required** (when as an edition, the value is present in the input but not detected by the validation)

Do you have a method to resolve both of these problems or maybe I am doing something wrong ?

*Thanks for your help*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your issues are due to the problem that you're are not using RHF's `<Controller />` component: For external controlled components like Material UI's `<TextField />` you have to use this, as right now RHF has no chance to link the `<TextField />` to its form state, as `register` isn't working with external controlled components. Check this [section](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries) in the docs for more information.

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email().required("Email required"),
});

const {
  control,
  handleSubmit,
  reset,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm({
  mode: "onChange",
  reValidateMode: "all",
  resolver: yupResolver(schema),
});

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`localhost/api/user/${route.params.userId}`).then(async (r) => {
    let userDatas = await r.json();
    reset(userDatas);
  });
}, [route.params.userId]);

const onSubmit = async (datas) => {
  console.log(datas);
};

const handleVerifyDuplicate = (async) => {
  //This function check that the email is not yet used in the database
};

return (
  <form autoComplete="off" noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <Controller
      name="email"
      control={control}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
        <TextField
          name="email"
          label="Email"
          margin="dense"
          variant="outlined"
          required
          value={value}
          onChange={(event) => {
            handleVerifyDuplicate(event);
            onChange(event);
          }}
        />
      )}
    />

    <Button
      id="btn-save"
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      size="small"
      startIcon={<SaveIcon />}
      type="submit"
    >
      Save
    </Button>
  </form>
);
```

I think you also don't need the second `useEffect`, as you can just use RHF `reset` after you have fetched the user data from your API.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)